# Query to retrieve all the lines involved in a documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a structure with document, and lines. A line has a reference to it's document. However some lines can also have a reference to another line.

I want to make a query to retrieve all the lines involved in a documents (meaning lines directly linked, and the referenced lines).

Example

```
{_id:1, doc:1 },
{_id:3, doc:1, linkedLine:4},
{_id:4, doc:2 },
{_id:5, doc:2 },
```

I would like to obtain

```
linesOfDoc(1) = {_id:1, doc:1},{_id:3, doc:1, linkedLine:4},{_id:4, doc:2 }
```

I could be done getting first lines with doc=1, the doing a loop and getting the linked lines if present.

**But is that possible to do this in one mongodb query ?**

Regards

Comment: why is `{_id:4, doc:2 }` in the result?

Comment: `{_id:4, doc:2 }` is in the result because of `{_id:3, doc:1, parent:4}` that points to `_id:4`

Comment: Renaming parent to linkedLine to make it clearer.

Comment: will "embedding" the linkedLine ("parent") to the "child" document be suitable for you, or must it be flattened as your specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do joins with mongo, exactly as you would do with sql, but you can get close with [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).

You got all the data in one query, but you need to flatten it farther to get the exact result you specified.

```
MONGO> db.playground.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "doc" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "doc" : 1, "linkedLine" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 4, "doc" : 2 }

MONGO> db.playground.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: "playground", localField: "linkedLine", foreignField: "_id", as: "embeddedLinkedLine"}}, { $match: { doc: <id of the document youre looking for> }}])
{ "_id" : 1, "doc" : 1, "embeddedLinkedLine" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "doc" : 1, "linkedLine" : 4, "embeddedLinkedLine" : [ { "_id" : 4, "doc" : 2 } ] }
```